# How to configure SimpleCov to ignore #inspect methods

Tags: simplecov

My coverage report is not at 100% because I have a couple of #inspect methods in my classes which I use for debugging purposes. Is there a way to configure SimpleCov to ignore all the inspect methods?

Answer (score 29):

I know I'm late to this, but I had to do the same thing and discovered the solution.

Wrap your code with `# :nocov:` comments like so:

```
# :nocov:
def my_debug_method
  do_something
end
# :nocov:
```

Documentation here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/simplecov/SimpleCov/Configuration#nocov_token-instance_method

Comment: this works, but is there no way of globally defining methods to ignore everywhere in the code, based on name (+ namespace ?) .

Just like the original question that asked how to ignore methods named `#inspect`, say I want to ignore methods named `to_s`, but I dont want to add two lines (`# :nocov:`) for every class that has the `to_s` method in my code